# Printing object's keys and values

Tags: javascript, json

I want to print a key: value pair from javascript object. I can have different keys in my array so cannot hardcode it to object[0].key1

```
var filters = [{"user":"abc"},{"application":"xyz"}];
console.log(Object.keys(filters[0])[0]); // prints user
var term = (Object.keys(filters[0])[0]);
console.log(filters[0].term); // prints undefined
```

How can i print the value of the key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is looking for a `term` property on `filters[0]`:

```
console.log(filters[0].term);
```

What you actually want to do is use the *value* of `term` (in your example that will be `"user"`) as the property identifier:

```
console.log(filters[0][term]);
```

Answer (score 31):

```
for (var key in filters[0]){
    console.log( key + ": " + filters[0][key]);
}
```

Or if you want to print all the values of filters

```
for (var i in filters){
    console.log(i);
    for (var key in filters[i]){
        console.log( key + ": " + filters[i][key]);
    }
}
```

##On @mplungjan 's comment

```
filters.forEach(function(obj, index){
    console.log(index);
    for (var key in obj){
        console.log(key, obj[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: for in is not recommended for arrays and you should keep key and i local

Answer (score 8):

for loop for array and for..in iteration for object:

```js
var filters = [{ "user": "abc"}, {"application": "xyz"}];

for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) { // the plainest of array loops
  var obj = filters[i];
  // for..in object iteration will set the key for each pair
  // and the value is in obj[key]
  for (var key in obj) { 
    console.log(key, obj[key])
  }
}
```

ES6

```js
[{ "user": "abc"}, {"application": "xyz"}].forEach(
  obj => console.log(Object.entries(obj).flat())
)
```

Comment: can you please explain "o" and obj[o], how does they represent "key" and "value", link to detailed documentation will be helpful

Answer (score 4):

You can access the value using array syntax

```
var filters = [{"user":"abc"},{"application":"xyz"}];
console.log(Object.keys(filters[0])[0]); // prints user
var term = (Object.keys(filters[0])[0]);
console.log(filters[0][term]);// prints abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that we have a mode object that has some strings in it for example. If we were to do `MODE.toString()` with just alpha, beta, gamma in the object, what will be returned is `[object Object]` which is not useful.

Instead, lets say we wanted to get something nice back like `Normal, Sepia, Psychedelic`. To do that, we could add a `toString: function(){...}` to our object that will do just that. One catch to this however is that if we loop through everything in the object, the function it self will also be printed, so we need to check for that. In the example I'll check `toString` specifically, however, other checks like `... && typeof MODE[key] == "string"` could be used instead

Following is some example code, calling `MODE.toString();` will return `Normal, Sepia, Psychedelic`

```
var MODE = {alpha:"Normal", beta:"Sepia", gamma:"Psychedelic",
    toString: function() {
        var r = "";
        for (var key in MODE) {
            if (MODE.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "toString") {
                r+= r !== "" ? ", ":"";
                r+= MODE[key];
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get all keys in array of object, you can try this one mybe

```
      let temp = []
        let keys = []
        let result = []
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          temp = Object.keys(data[i])
          for (let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            if(!keys.includes(temp[j])){
              keys.push(temp[j])
            }

          }
          temp = []
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
              if(data[i][keys[j]] == undefined){
                data[i][keys[j]] = ""
              }

            }

        }
        return data
```

or this one if you want take the key from same array 2dimension

```
            function convertObj(arr){
            let arrResult = []
            for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let obj={}
            for (let j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                obj[arr[0][j]] = arr[i][j]

            }
            arrResult.push(obj)  

            }
        return arrResult
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print key and value, even for nested object then you can try this function:

```
function printObjectData(obj, n = 0){
    let i = 0;
    var properties = Object.keys(obj);

    let tab = "";
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tab += "\t";

    for(i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){                  
        if(typeof(obj[properties[i]]) == "object"){
            console.log(tab + properties[i] + ":");
            printObjectData(obj[properties[i]], n + 1);
        }
        else
            console.log(tab + properties[i] + " : " + obj[properties[i]]);                    
    }
}

printObjectData(filters);
```

and the solution will look like this:

```
0:
    user : abc 
1:
    application : xyz
```

and if you want to remove 0: and  1:
then simply remove

```
console.log(tab + properties[i] + ":");
```

after the if statement