# Foreach element Javascript json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I got a JSON like this:

```
{
    "email.com": ["email@email.com|username\r"],
    "email.de": ["email@email.de|username"]
}
```

I want to get it printet like this:

> email.com
>   email.de

```js
var data = '{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + obj[i]; // I want to get email.com , email.de
}
```

```html
<div id="types">
</div>
```

Comment: it's about to get just an object property names. Is `username` not considered?

Comment: no i just want to get email.com and email.de the name of the arrays

Comment: if so, there's no need to parse that string

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```js
var data = '{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + keys[i]; // I want to get email.com , email.de
}
```

```html
<div id="types"></div>
```

Comment: You know now i want to get to the children of that keys can you help me

Comment: var data = '{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var keys = obj;
for (var x in obj) {
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
   document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + obj[x];
  }
}

Comment: And if you want, you can do the first one in the same way like this:

var data = '{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var keys = obj;
for (var x in obj) {
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
   document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + x;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}];
var term = (Object.keys(data[0])[0]);

var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + obj[i][term]; // I want to get email.com , email.de
}
```

This should work

[Printing object's keys and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478742/printing-objects-keys-and-values)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: filters is not defined

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `String.match` and `Array.join` functions:

```js
var data = '{"email.com":["email@email.com|username\r"],"email.de":["email@email.de|username"]}',
    emails = data.match(/\w+\.\w+(?=\":\[)/g).join("<br>");
    
document.getElementById('types').innerHTML += '<br>' + emails;
// 'emails' variable contains "email.com<br>email.de"
```

```html
<div id="types"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

quickly :

```
var obj = {
    "email.com": ["email@email.com|username\r"],
    "email.de": ["email@email.de|username"]
};
for (var prop in obj)  console.log(prop);
```